# DuckDB Not saving huge database

Tags: python, duckdb

We are trying to embed duckdb in our project but DuckDB doesn't seem to be able to save database after closing connection.

**Informations:**
Database size: 16Go
Amount of tables: 3

I searched for information about data not persisting and found nothing about whole database not persisting.

We are using the **Python API**, here is the setup:

```
%config SqlMagic.autopandas = True
%config SqlMagic.feedback = False
%config SqlMagic.displaycon = False

%sql duckdb:///./database.db
```

So everything works fine until we close the connection (or restart the environment).
We tried to investigate using the DuckDB CLI, but same result.

So if anyone have any idea why that would happen that'd be great, *this problem has nothing to do with SQL*, it is purely either a hardware or a software (duckdb) problem. If nobody has an answer I'll open a ticket on their repo.

**Python version:** 3.10.2 64-bit on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to [this bug](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/3952), which has been fixed in the 0.5.0 version. You can install it with `pip install duckdb==0.5.0`

Comment: This is correct. I had the same issue in R with a large database 10GB+ where after I built my database in ver 0.4.0, the tables were no longer accessible after I quit my R session and opened a new session the next day. In a new R session, once I made a connection to the database using `dbListTables(con)` it showed no tables. I reverted to the development version of duckdb (0.3.2-2) from (0.4.0), rebuilt my database using the dev version and it resolved the problem I was having. We may get a version 0.4.1 soon that fixes this error so keep an eye out on the duckdb github.

Comment: @On_an_island I'm struggling with the same issue but can't find a source for the development version. Do you know where I can source it?

Comment: @hisspott when you do `install.packages("duckdb")` I believe it asks if you want to compile? If you say no, it should install the prior version and not the current version which is 0.4.0. See if that works. One thing that came out of installing the earlier version (0.3.2-2) is quite a significant slow down in performance for me so I re-installed the current version and instead split my database in multiple files to stay below 10gb size.

Comment: @On_an_island thanks for the response.  That's really helpful I'm not seeing those options on reinstall but will check Cran and see if I can find the older version. This bug has already cost me two days of work and I thought it was something I was doing. So frustrating.

Comment: @hisspott my apologies...I forgot this was a python post...not R. Unfortunately, I'm working in R so I won't be very helpful.

Comment: In DuckDB [help](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/index) page you can see instructions on how to install both the release and the development version on Python and R (among other options). Anyway, DuckDB version 0.5.0 was released today with lots of bugs fixed. I have managed to install it on R using `install.packages("https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/releases/download/v0.5.0/duckdb_r_src.tar.gz", repos = NULL)` and on Python using `pip install duckdb==0.5.0`. Note that, in the absence of binaries for your OS, you most probably will need to setup a build enviroment (Rtools for R is enough)